# Eclipse XML editor shows android1 not android and no auto-complete

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm using eclipse for Android programming, Today when i open to resume my app development the xml editor did't know the android tag at all like android:layout_...., It's knows android1 and the auto complete not working and says "Element  is unknown"!

Here's an example :

```
<TextView
    android1:id="@+id/textView1"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignRight="@+id/help"
    android1:textSize="20dp" />
```

Any ideas to solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may have messed up your namespaces. So in your XML layout files, replace all `xmlns:` tags with:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

This should be in your top-level element, and it should look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/help"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```